How to implement pagination for spring boot, graphql with mongoDB as backend?
Assume I have the graphql defined with
type Query {
  book(id: ID!): Book
  books(first: Int, last: Int, before: String, after: String): BookConnection
}
type Book {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

How would I implement the Connection-based approach?
The examples provided by spring-data are based on JPA.
Unfortunately, the documentation spring graphql pagination is not clear enough to derive what needs to be written in the BookRepository interface (which extends MongoRepository<Book, String>) as well as in the Controller which implements the queries.
Suggested configuration did not result in a working solution:
    GraphQLTypeVisitor visitor = ConnectionFieldTypeVisitor.create(List.of(
        new WindowConnectionAdapter(strategy),
        new SliceConnectionAdapter(strategy)));
    GraphQlSource.schemaResourceBuilder()
        .schemaResources(new ClassPathResource("graphql/book.graphqls"))
        .configureTypeDefinitions(new ConnectionTypeDefinitionConfigurer())
        .typeVisitors(List.of(visitor));

I've used gradle build with
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'
}

A full working example would be appreciated.

Please try to google spring boot graphql mongodb pagination

@RoarS. unfortunately, I have not found a combination of spring-boot with both graphql AND MongoDB explaining how pagination should work.
there are examples for spring-boot+graphQL+JPA (e.g. hibernate) but not with mongoDB...

https://spring.io/guides/topicals/observing-graphql-in-action

@BrianClozel thank you very much for the link. I'm still struggling to understand this
Window<Track> findByIdInOrderByTitle(Set<String> trackIds, ScrollPosition scrollPosition, Limit limit);
why do we need to pass in the trackIds if the scroll position is provided separately?
any recommendations on how to understand the underlying logic/implementation?

you don't necessarily need to lookup by id, just to provide enough elements to issue a stable database query. "find by name 'Joe' and get the first 10 elements after element X" works too.

@BrianClozel, thanks again for your prompt answer. I'm ok with looking up by id (or the cursor). I'm not clear how the method signature (and name) should be to make it work.
My expectation is that it should simply accept ScrollPosition and Limit...
I do realise that my understanding is lacking, but it's not clear to me where to look up what's needed to make the function of the interface work.

my current theory: Window<MyObject> findAllBy(ScrollPosition scrollPosition, Limit limit, Sort sort); this gives me a way to specify sorting. In my case it's Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("nested.property.name")); I'll spend some time investigating the performance of this approach and what queries are being executed for each paginated call.
